# calculating balance of different assets using payment information in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe. What I want is to calculate the balance of all different types of tokens per address by quarter. This requires summing payment (either debit- or credit+) for all addresses by token overtime (from the very start) since I want to observe the evolution of balance of all tokens per address quarterly.

My current df

```
....
        token_address       address              payment            date        ... more columns ...
11      0x48c80f1f4d53d55   0xdde7f77766434b6fb  6e+17              2016-10-15 
12      0x1e797ce986c3cff   0xda48c91e051ccb1ec -1e+19              2016-12-24 
13      0x1e797ce986c3cff   0xda48c91e051ccb1ec -5e+19              2016-12-24 
14      0x45e42d659d9f946   0x0d0f998d0eacc304c -1541212.0          2016-12-24 
15      0x48c80f1f4d53d59   0xe0a6f3da1e523f2d8 -5.3282558e+19      2016-12-24 
16      0x1e797ce986c3cff   0xda48c91e051ccb1ec  7e+19              2017-02-03 
527     0xedbaf3c5100302d   0xcf62dfc079c5d594c -5205.0             2017-02-03
528     0xedbaf3c5100302d   0xcf62dfc079c5d594c -1245205.0          2017-02-03
529     0xedbaf3c5100302d   0xd9ffae429218a2ff3 -129500000.0        2017-02-03
164207  0xedbaf3c5100302d   0xcf62dfc079c5d594c  1000000.0          2017-09-23
164208  0xf230b790e05390f   0x74f3f5d29f71805c7  27518.0            2017-09-23
164209  0xd26114cd6ee289a   0x8b06df3a4ad049865  7718036541774558.0 2017-09-23
164210  0x1e797ce986c3cff   0xda48c91e051ccb1ec  1e+19              2017-09-23

....
```

The desired output

```
address             date   token_address        balance
0xdde7f77766434b6fb 2016Q4 0x48c80f1f4d53d55     6e+17  
0xda48c91e051ccb1ec 2016Q4 0x1e797ce986c3cff    -6e+19
0xda48c91e051ccb1ec 2017Q1 0x1e797ce986c3cff     1e+19
0xda48c91e051ccb1ec 2017Q3 0x1e797ce986c3cff     2e+19
0x0d0f998d0eacc304c 2016Q4 0x45e42d659d9f946    -1541212.0
0xe0a6f3da1e523f2d8 2016Q4 0x48c80f1f4d53d59    -5.3282558e+19
0xcf62dfc079c5d594c 2017Q1 0xedbaf3c5100302d    -1250410
0xcf62dfc079c5d594c 2017Q3 0xedbaf3c5100302d    -250410
0xd9ffae429218a2ff3 2017Q1 0xedbaf3c5100302d    -129500000.0
0x74f3f5d29f71805c7 2017Q3 0xf230b790e05390f    27518.0
0x8b06df3a4ad049865 2017Q3 0xd26114cd6ee289a    7718036541774558.0
```

any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: I don't have time today to give you a full answer but maybe tomorrow (if you want). Go ahead and do the following. 1. calculate a new column "quarter" by using the apply function on balance. To do that you write a function that determines the correct quarter and pass it to apply. 2. initialize an empty dictionary. 3. Iterate over the dataframe using df.iterrows() and for each line do: if (address, quarter, token_address) in empty_dict[(address, quarter, token_address)]: empty_dict[(address, quarter, token_address)] += [balance] else empty_dict[(address, quarter, token_address)] = [balance] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `date` to quarters using `PeriodIndex`, then use `groupby` + `sum` to get the quarterly sum; then `groupby` + `cumsum` for the final output:

```
out = (df.groupby(['address', pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq='Q'), 'token_address'])['payment'].sum()
      .groupby(level=[0,2]).cumsum().reset_index(name='balance'))
```

Output:

```
                address    date      token_address       balance
0   0x0d0f998d0eacc304c  2016Q4  0x45e42d659d9f946 -1.541212e+06
1   0x74f3f5d29f71805c7  2017Q3  0xf230b790e05390f  2.751800e+04
2   0x8b06df3a4ad049865  2017Q3  0xd26114cd6ee289a  7.718037e+15
3   0xcf62dfc079c5d594c  2017Q1  0xedbaf3c5100302d -1.250410e+06
4   0xcf62dfc079c5d594c  2017Q3  0xedbaf3c5100302d -2.504100e+05
5   0xd9ffae429218a2ff3  2017Q1  0xedbaf3c5100302d -1.295000e+08
6   0xda48c91e051ccb1ec  2016Q4  0x1e797ce986c3cff -6.000000e+19
7   0xda48c91e051ccb1ec  2017Q1  0x1e797ce986c3cff  1.000000e+19
8   0xda48c91e051ccb1ec  2017Q3  0x1e797ce986c3cff  2.000000e+19
9   0xdde7f77766434b6fb  2016Q4  0x48c80f1f4d53d55  6.000000e+17
10  0xe0a6f3da1e523f2d8  2016Q4  0x48c80f1f4d53d59 -5.328256e+19
```

Comment: No, this is not the correct way, since this separately calculates the balance for each quarter. I need the cumulative sum since what I am looking for is the "evolution" of token balance. you can see that my balance and your balance don't match.

Comment: @Olive I edited the answer. It matches the expected output now.